# Python/imaplib - How to get messages' labels?

Tags: python, gmail, imaplib

I'm using imaplib for my project because I need to access gmails accounts.
Fact: With gmail's labels each message may be on an arbitrary number of folders/boxes/labels.

The problem is that I would like to get every single label from every single message.

The first solution it cames to my mind is to use "All Mail" folder to get all messages and then, for each message, check if that message is in each one of the available folders.

However, I find this solution heavy and I was wondering if there's a better way to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: Example code at https://gist.github.com/1323795

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To get all the labels for a given message within gmail you can do the following

```
t, d = imapconn.uid('FETCH', uid, '(X-GM-LABELS)')
or
t, d = imapconn.fetch(uid, '(X-GM-LABELS)')
```

BTW: You can find more on gmail imap extensions at http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/imap/

Comment: Thank you so much!
That was exactly what I was looking for =D

Comment: Hey, I have a similar question, (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24361257/how-can-i-save-draft-with-details-in-gmail-via-imaplib-in-python), could you step by and have a look? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in imap you don't have labels, gmail 'emulates' them on imap, you can low at the raw source of a message picked from imap an check if it has some custom header with the label

Comment: I understand what're you saying and, first of all, thank you for the help. 
However, I don't think that's the way. Gmail doesn't seem to mark the messages with any custom header for the label. What makes sense, otherwise they would have to change the message every time a user adds/changes/removes a label from an email. They just seem to have boxes and a message (possibly, a reference to the message) can be in many boxes at the same time.

Comment: so I think you can get (RFC822.HEADER) for each message, you can use uid('FETCH', '1:*' , '(RFC822.HEADER)') (don't known there is a specific imaplib command), since messageid is not enough, then hash the result i.e. using md5 or sha, the make a python dict with folders. for each message in all folder you can check for existence in each folder.
It's not very optimal, but with gmail you can have same message in multiple folders since they are rally multiple labels, gmail does not offers a custom header. Anyway the overall process is not very slow since you are picking only headers

Comment: you may use also use only message-id+sender+dest+date